# How to draw directly on the screen in windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

Say for example that I wanted to draw a red square (or multiple red squares) in the middle of the screen and still be able to see everything not covered by the square, a little bit like a splash screen.

I want to implement this in windows but I don't know the best way to draw on top of the screen. These are my ideas so far:

- I initially attempted to draw directly onto the desktop by obtaining a Device Context for it.
- Make the rectangle/s a separate window as they would be very easy to move around and I wouldn't have to worry about transparency.
- Create a transparent window that covers the entire screen and stays on top. Draw the rectangle/s on the client area of the screen

I think that the best of the 3 ideas is the last one, but any opinions on my ideas, or new ideas would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Basic suggestion, Your title shouldn't be `"How to impliment Screen snake in windows?"`, it should be `"How to draw directly on the screen in windows`" or something of that favor.  You have to put the emphasis on the problem you're trying to solve, not on the project that it's for.  you'll get a better response that way.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have made the changes and agree that the question is definitely clearer now :)

Comment: I will vote to re-open your question if you edit the body of your question to focus more on the problem of drawing on the screen than of the specific Screen-snake game.

Answer (score 3):

Creating transparent window, then drawing in it, in my experience it is messy.
Why don't you just take a screenshot from the back ground set it as the back ground for you snake game. When ever they click somewhere/die you just close your game. 
You could catch the last click and resubmit it after closing the game.

That is how I would do, but of course that just an opinion.

Comment: I have seen screensavers that work this way, but I found it mildly annoying that the screen didn't update (clock, progress bar, etc).

Comment: I agree, although it is a nice suggestion :)